# Trouble with Particle system and forcefields

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, bezier-curves, force-fields, depth-of-field

I have a simple particle system that is using an object (an icosphere subdivided a few times) with an emitter shader(color:red and strength: 15) and the particle system is affected only by a force field(a bezier curve that could be the culprit).

So that it goes where I want it to go, the problem is with the light leaving a trail behind itself while being directed by the force-field, what I'd like to happen is that the particles leaves not trails but just glows in the night, I'm currently using Cycles Render just to be clear and also I'm not sure 100% but I have the camera Depth Of Field activated as well as Motion Blur so I'm wandering a bit if it ain't one of those two making light leave that trail.

I have the latest version of Blender, the 2.78.1

I'm rendering with my CUDA GPU(nvidia GTX 850) and I'm on ArchLinux.

[image: A render of the scene at 512 samples]

Here is what I'd like to aim for but the light is still leaving a trail almost on the verge of disappearing !

[image: Render of the scene with square samples and a total of 22500 samples]

If someone wants to test this with the .blend just ask, I'll provide it.

Comment: Without knowing anything else, I would guess that it is the motion blur. Just try a render with that turned off.

Comment: Yeah that worked perfectly, Thank you very much you should answer the question so that I can valid it since you gave me the solution.